# Не переведён текст в редакторе для нового функционала по загрузке картинок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн, редактор

Не переведён текст в редакторе после выкатки нового функционала по загрузке картинок: [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/260198).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Текст про лицензию: `cce8cccd6a9690d3e65df3a65c6a4282`. Добавил перевод:

   > Пользовательский контент попадает под действие лицензии cc by-sa
   >   3.0 с указанием ссылки на источник
2. Текст про максимальный размер пикчи: `451f81c273fedb6b1c2fbb2fb7c03cb5`. Добавил перевод:

   > **Перетащите сюда изображение** **или нажмите для выбора файла** (не более 2 мегабайт)
3. Текст ошибки при загрузке большого файла: `517bc79de3a03225c2067c7dbc3d241e`. Добавил перевод:

   > Изображение слишком большое (более 2 мегабайт).